# How to hide on screen navbar from Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I develop an app for WP 8 and need to hide onscreen NavBar. But I don't know how to do it from the WP 8 app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to hide **system tray**?

If so, you can do this in both `Universal app` and `Silverlight app`.

In Windows phone Universal app:

Add this code in your app.xaml.cs or behind code of page.

```
StatusBar statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

// Hide the status bar
await statusBar.HideAsync();
```

And in Windows phone silverlight app:

add this in your xaml of Page:

```
Shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

If it is virtual nav bar at bottom, you can try this:

[ApplicationView.SuppressSystemOverlays | suppressSystemOverlays property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.suppresssystemoverlays(v=win.10).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, I mean onscreen NavBar which used to display and handle system buttons: back, windows and search.

Comment: ApplicationView is a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML, but I need an ability to do the same thing from a windows phone 8 app

Comment: Windows Phone 8 didn't support "soft" navigation bars, therefore there are no APIs for it. You could try via reflection if you are careful to handle errors.